# JavaScript function is running automatically on page load

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to create a calculator and in that I have applied onclick event listener on every button.
But somehow, the JavaScript function is running automatically. 
Following is the JS code:

```
var firstOperand, secondOperand, result=0, resultOnScreen;
document.getElementById('one').onclick = getOperand(1);
document.getElementById('two').onclick = getOperand(2);
document.getElementById('three').onclick = getOperand(3);
document.getElementById('four').onclick = getOperand(4);
document.getElementById('five').onclick = getOperand(5);
document.getElementById('six').onclick = getOperand(6);
document.getElementById('seven').onclick = getOperand(7);
document.getElementById('eight').onclick = getOperand(8);
document.getElementById('nine').onclick = getOperand(9);
document.getElementById('zero').onclick = getOperand(0);
document.getElementById('doubleZero').onclick = getOperand(00); 

function getOperand(selectedNumber) {
    resultOnScreen = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML;
    resultOnScreen = resultOnScreen.concat(selectedNumber);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultOnScreen;
}
```

> Note: Here 'one','two', and so on are the ids of the respective buttons.

I have checked through a lot of answers on Stack Overflow but none helped.

Comment: Pass a *function* which calls `getOperand` with the argument you need - you're invoking `getOperand` 11 times on pageload at the moment

Comment: Tried that even, still it was of now use.

Comment: Note, you can also partially apply the function by doing `getOperand.bind(null, 1)` for `1` and so on.

Comment: Also `getOperand(00)` will not give you double zero - it's just a single zero.

Comment: You can use the following formats for each one... `.onclick = function() { getOperand(1); }` or `.onclick = () => getOperand(1)`

Comment: @VLAZ is correct that `00` is just going to send the value of `0` to the function... so as you're dealing with concatenation of strings, instead of passing numeric values, send their string representations directly (e.g. `getOperand("1");` and `getOperand("00");`)